# Does "Sacrifice a creature" trigger "sacrifice this creature"

Tags: magic-the-gathering

When choosing a creature to sacrifice (originated from a "sacrifice a creature" instruction), if the creature that is being sacrificed has "sacrifice this creature (for whatever result)", does it trigger?

Does it make any difference if the target creature is a forced sacrifice instead of a volunteered sacrifice?

Example scenario:
I play [Altar's Reap](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=226890) to draw 2 cards and target [Bile Urchin](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=74427) as the sacrifice. Does this trigger Bile Urchin's "*Sacrifice Bile Urchin: Target player loses 1 life.*"?

I may have thought about this for too long and confused myself, so a little clarification would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**It will not.** Sacrificing is a cost paid for the effect to go on stack. Just like you can not spend 1 mana on different costs, you can not spend 1 creature on different costs.

If you wanted it to work the way you described, the ability should be a triggered one, for example it could read: 'When this creature is sacrificed, ...'.

(Also, keep in mind that sacrificing is not **targeting** anything. Untargettable creatures can still be sacrificed)